# Django - Form is getting submitted but nothing saves in database

Tags: python, mysql, django, phpmyadmin, xampp

My form is getting submitted by in phpmyadmin nothing get saved please help.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Customers(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   .
.
.
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mar_stat=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table="customers"
```

---

Views.py

```
def customerreg(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.POST.get('first_name') and request.POST.get('last_name') and request.POST.get('gender') and request.POST.get('dob') and request.POST.get('email') and request.POST.get('phno') and request.POST.get('designation') and request.POST.get('address') and request.POST.get('mar_stat'):
            saverecord = Customers()
            saverecord.first_name=request.POST.get('first_name')
            .
            saverecord.mar_stat=request.POST.get('mar_stat')
            saverecord.save()
            messages.success(request, "New User Registration Saved Successfully. You may close the window!")
            return render(request,'index.html')
    else:
            return render(request,'index.html')
```

---

Index.html

```
    <form method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
    <table border="7">
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="first_name" required/></td>
       .
.
.
.


                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    {% if messages %}
    {% for result in messages %}
    <b style="color: green;">{{result}}</b>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried everything and im mostly sure that my indentation is right still it throws an error. What to do?

Comment: please also provide forms.py file related to this view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing wrong in views.

Instead of this:

```
def customerreg(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.POST.get('first_name') and request.POST.get('last_name') and request.POST.get('gender') and request.POST.get('dob') and request.POST.get('email') and request.POST.get('phno') and request.POST.get('designation') and request.POST.get('address') and request.POST.get('mar_stat'):
            saverecord = Customers()
            saverecord.first_name=request.POST.get('first_name')
            .
            saverecord.mar_stat=request.POST.get('mar_stat')
            saverecord.save()
            messages.success(request, "New User Registration Saved Successfully. You may close the window!")
            return render(request,'index.html')
    else:
            return render(request,'index.html')
```

Do this way:

```
def customerreg(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        if request.POST.get('first_name') and request.POST.get('last_name') and request.POST.get('gender') and request.POST.get('dob') and request.POST.get('email') and request.POST.get('phno') and request.POST.get('designation') and request.POST.get('address') and request.POST.get('mar_stat'):
            saverecord = Customers()
            saverecord.first_name=request.POST.get('first_name')
            .
            saverecord.mar_stat=request.POST.get('mar_stat')
            saverecord.save()
            messages.success(request, "New User Registration Saved Successfully. You may close the window!")
            return redirect('/login/')  #made changes here
    return render(request,'index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

for Add data You need to write code like this...

```
def customerreg(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        f_name= request.POST.get('first_name') 
        l_name= request.POST.get('last_name')
        gender=request.POST.get('gender') 
        dob=request.POST.get('dob') 
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        phno=request.POST.get('phno') 
        designation=request.POST.get('designation')
        address=request.POST.get('address') 
        mar_stat=request.POST.get('mar_stat')
        Customers(
            first_name=f_name,
            last_name=l_name,
            gender=gender,
            dob=dob,
            email=email,
            phno=phno,
            designation=designation,
            address=address,
            mar_stat=mar_stat
        ).save()
            
        messages.success(request, "New User Registration Saved Successfully. You may close the window!")
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request,'index.html')
```